Cluster Analysis Multivariate analysis
I have 84 variables in total and more 600,000 rows in in excel. I want to run hierarchical cluster analysis for this data or k means and get the optimum cluster through elbow method and silhouette index.
I have run my data through RStudio but all I get is std: bad alloc also in stata version 17.0 but it can only process k means clustering. Any suggestions of other open-source statistical tools I can use? Or any recommendation to where I can run my data?

Welcome to SO. Please familiarise yourself with how to ask a good question and provide a minimal reproducible example to try to reproduce the error and debug it.
This sounds like an OOM issue. How much memory is available, and what is in your R environment? Making more memory available to R might help.
